# Extremal graphs for paths of fixed length

Tags: graph-theory, forbidden-subgraphs

One can show that if $G$ is a graph on $n$ vertices and does not contain a path (cycles do not count) of length $k$, then $e(G) \leq \frac{k-1}{2}n$ (by induction - remove a vertex of minimal degree which turns out to be $\leq \frac{k-1}{2}$ by Ore's theorem). There are certainly examples attaining this for $k$ dividing $n$ - say, $\frac{n}{k}$ disjoint copies of the complete graph on $k$ vertices.

So in general my guess if that the possible maximum for any $n$ and $k$ is $\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}n \rfloor$. How can we describe all extremal graphs?

Comment: I'm guessing that $e(G)$ is the number of edges in $G$, and I'm guessing the "maximum" in your second paragraph is the maximum possible number of edges in a graph on $n$ vertices containing no path of length $k$. So if $n=4$ and $k=3$, I guess you're saying that the maximum number of edges in a graph on $4$ vertices with no path of length $3$ is $4$? I don't see it. I can only find two graphs with $4$ vertices and $4$ edges, and each of them contains a path of length $3$. What am I missing?